# Material UI Drawer component is hiding underlying navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I am trying out Drawer component of Google's material UI library. I have it configured and working but the problem is, it's overlapping on the underlying navigation bar on my web app. Is there a way I can have the drawer functionality of this library restricted to {entireScreen - topNavigationBar} area?

[image: Pic for reference, basically I want top blue bar to be visible even when drawer is open(left side only)]

Here is what my render function returns

```
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.handleLeftOpen}>Menu</Button>
                <Drawer
                    open={this.state.open.left}
                    onRequestClose={this.handleLeftClose}
                    onClick={this.handleLeftClose}>
                    {leftDrawerList}
                </Drawer>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Drawer styles, you'll see that it has `z-index: 1300` property. So I suppose you should give your Navbar z-index that is greater than `1300`